# Audio is to sound as blank is to smell?

Tags: single-word-requests

As title states trying to understand better.
I  learned that Audible for smell is Olfactible.

But Audio for smell is?

Comment: So far we do not have a technology to record, transmit, or reproduce smells.  So (when we do) then we will find out whether they call it "olfactio".

Comment: Please give an example context.

Comment: 'Audio' and 'Video' are both derived from Latin (sensus auditus and sensus visus respectively according to [this online translator](https://imtranslator.net/translation/english/to-latin/translation/)) and and the same translator gives "sensus odor" as the Latin for the sense of smell. If the world of technology is consistent when it comes to naming then one would expect "smellyvision" equipment (if it is ever developed) to be referred to as "odoreo" or "odorio" equipment. but, even if it is developed, I suspect that it will be called something completely different.

Comment: Several decades ago, John Waters introduced [Odorama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyester_(film))—a scratch-and-sniff card that moviegoers were supposed to activate, smell by smell at key moments in the film Polyester. However, Wikipedia reports that 3M invented [sctratch-and-sniff technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_and_sniff) in 1965. So while **Odorama** might sound like a better match for _audio_ and _video_, **scratch-and-sniff** might have the stronger historical claim. And if you're just looking for a nice synonym for _odoriferousness_, **redolence** is a nice option.

Answer (score 2):

"Audio" means "digital or analog signal representing sound by indicating the variation of air pressure over time." I don't believe we have any technology for producing signals that represent scents in an analogous way, so there is no analogous word for scent.

"Audio" is originally the Latin word for "I hear," and "video" is Latin for "I see," so if scent signals ever become commonplace, we might refer to them using the Latin word for "I smell." According to Wiktionary, that word is "[olfacio](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/olfacio#Latin)" (not "olfactio").